# Where is OpenCV lib folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opencv

OpenCV documentation [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC++) refers to a lib folder that doesn't exist after I checkout the OpenCV from the repository (https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/branches/2.3). There is a lib folder that is only existend after I build under OpenCV/build/lib which has another folder called Debug. Can I just use this folder? instead and have C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\lib\Debug in my additional libraries in VS2008?

Comment: 4 years later I have the same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed source from the repository has no prebuilt OpenCV binaries.

On Windows (MSVC) you need to build `INSTALL` project two times (in Debug and Release configurations). It will create an `install` folder with all needed binaries, headers and miscellaneous files.

By the way, OpenCV repository is recently migrated to the new hosting:
http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/branches/2.3/

Comment: I am confused. What is the best way to install openCV to work with VS 2008 Professional? Install already built binary or build it through Cmake?? Which one is easier and just works?